# How does redirect to returnUrl work in Asp.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I've started a new MVC 5 site, using the new Asp.Net Identity with Owin. In my "account" controller which has the attribute [Authorize], I have fairly standard actions;

```
   // GET: /User/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        } 

// POST: /User/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var userApi = new UserService();
                    var apiUser = await userApi.LogIn(UserManager, model.CardNumber, model.Pin, model.RememberMe);

                    if (apiUser != null)
                    {
                        await SignInAsync(apiUser, model.RememberMe);
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                        {                                   
                            return RedirectToAction("UserLoggedIn", "User");    
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Cannot login {0}", ex.ToString());
                Response.AppendToLog(ex.ToString());
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.ToString());
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

My question is in regards to the returnUrl behavior, the code above works in the sense that, if a user is not logged in and calls a action in a controller that has the attribute [Authorize], it gets sent to the login actions above and then returned to the controller/action that was requested. Which is great, BUT how?? And is it safe?

In this article about "[Preventing open redirect attacks](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks)"(for earlier versions of Asp.Net MVC) the recommendation is to do a check on the returnUrl that it's a local url before doing the redirect, is that something I should still do or is it now handled by the framework?

Cheers,
Ola

Answer (score 18):

You need to check if the url is local indeed using this method (it is not handled by the framework automatically): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.islocalurl%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
{
  return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any source for the info that it is not handled? Seems strange that they would put in the functionality to redirect to returnUrl automatically but not follow their own guidelines in doing so. Hence the original question.

Comment: Why don't you try to manipulate the returnUrl and see what happens? By the way, in your code the `returnUrl` argument is never used.

Comment: Yeah I guess that would be one option. I know the returnUrl is never used in my action, but still the site redirects correctly, which is why I'm wondering how it works, magic or just that something happens to line up?Or is it that they've added automatic support for that stuff?

Comment: That's pretty strange behavior indeed. I can't find anything about the returnUrl handling in mvc 5, so I guess it should work the same as in the older versions.

Comment: I found this which talks about it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx but not really getting much wiser I must admit.

Comment: See the last code snippet in that article: `return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);` I assume this function performs the local url validation code in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As Sandeep Phadke told, the returnUrl Parameter is filled, because of configuration in startup.Auth.cs.

The CookieAuthenticationOptions has a property ReturnUrlParameter which is by Default set to "returnUrl". That is the reason, why it looks like magic. You can Change it to whatever you want:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        ReturnUrlParameter = "returnTo"
    });
```

Then you can Change the AccountController Login-Action to:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnTo)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnTo;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
       if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller");
        }
```

Comment: I know this code, the questions is if I need to use it or if this is handled in the framework for MVC5

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question on how the redirect Url is setup, it configured in `Startup.Auth.cs` which is called from `Startup.cs` and is marked with an attribute which is probably looked for by the OWIN framework on app startup and both files `partial` extend a `Startup` class.

In `Startup.Auth.cs` there's a class to configure authentication options and usually has the following code

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // ....
        // I deleted code which is commented out if you selected "Individual accounts" 
        // if you created the site project using the VS 2013 wizard
        // ...
    }
}
```

I added the `CookieSecure` option to ensure cookies were signed and that is recommended as a good security practice, other than that its boiler plate code.

More documentation on [CookieAuthenticationOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) if you want it.

Comment: If your entire website is in HTTPS, then it's redundant to use `CookieSecureOption.Always`. Besides, from the documentation, this forces you to use HTTPS for local development too. By default it's `CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest`. So if your website is in HTTPS, it's recommended to not change the `CookieSecure` property, since the default setting is secure enough.