# How to redirect a user from where He/She just come from after logging in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

I am building a E-Store web app. As a process there will be some actions that needs a user to be Authenticated first then can carry further steps. By default in ASP.Net identity when a user logs in He/She will be redirected to the index Action of the Home controller which is not what i want. I would like to redirect the user from where He/She came from. any idea?
Here is my controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

I am using ASP.Net MVC5 identity.

Comment: Did you try to use the search function of SO? If so it would give you this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628996/how-does-redirect-to-returnurl-work-in-asp-net-mvc5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default in ASP.Net identity when a user logs in He/She will be
>   redirected to the index Action of the Home controller which is not
>   what i want. I would like to redirect the user from where He/She came
>   from

This assumption is not entirely correct. The requested behavior is actually a default.

If you look at Login action (HTTPGET) you will notice that it has a `returnUrl` parameter. which is **filled by the OWIN middleware** when a 401 Unauthorized status code is changed to a 302 redirect onto the login path. `returnUrl` vallue is assigned to `ViewBag.ReturnUrl` which is later used to append this value Login postback URL(Login.cshtml view):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

Inside Login (HTTPPOST) action you can notice the same returnUrl parameter which is used to redirect the user to this url in case that Login was successful:

```
  case SignInStatus.Success:
      return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

So if for example you will place Authorize attribute on About action in Home controller and try to access it by typing in browser `http://localhost:.../Home/About` (replace ... with a port number) you will be redirected to Login action and once you login successfully you will be redirected to initially requested Home/About action

Comment: Thanks a Lot for your help. Saved me a day :)