# ASP.NET 5 - The ReturnUrl concept

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the ReturnUrl? In the ASP.NET 5 Web Appliation it returns you to Account/Login. I set Login as a Partial View on the Index Page, so I don't use the Login Page, but if I use an Action, which has the [Authorize] property and I'm not logged in, it returns me to Account/Login. What do I have to do to return me to the Index Page?

Thanks!

PS: the first comment is a solution for ASP.NET 4 MVC 5, not ASP.NET 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does redirect to returnUrl work in Asp.Net MVC5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628996/how-does-redirect-to-returnurl-work-in-asp-net-mvc5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect users, who are not logged in on custom page, you should configure in your Startup.cs in ConfigureServices() method:

```
        services.AddIdentity<User<string>, Role<string>>(
            options => {
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "Home/Index";
            }).AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```